# codeigniter- on change password display change password successful

Tags: php, codeigniter

My code so far is working and changing the user password. I would now like to display the user that their password was changed successfully else say try again but i cant make it happen. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Here is the controller:

```
public function change_password($arg = "admin")
{
    if(isset($_POST['data']) && !empty($_POST['data']))
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('data[oldpassword]', 'old password', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('data[password]', 'password', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('data[passconf]', 'password Confirmation', 'trim|required|md5|matches[data[password]]');



        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $data['requestee'] = $arg;
            $this->load->view('change_password', $data);
        }
        else
        {
            $data = $_POST['data'];
            array_pop($data);
            $data['requestee'] = $arg;
            $data['email'] = $this->session->userdata('email');
            //print_r($data); exit;

            if($data['requestee'] == "admin")
            {
                $this->load->model('login_model');
                if($this->login_model->updatepassword($data))
                {
                    redirect('/admin/show', 'refresh');
                }
                else
                {
                    redirect('login/change_password/');
                }
            }
            elseif($data['requestee'] == "org")
            {
                $this->load->model('login_model');
                if($this->login_model->updatepassword($data))
                {
                    redirect('/organizer/show', 'refresh');
                }
                else
                {
                    redirect('login/change_password/org');
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                echo "could not change password";
            }
        }
    }
    else 
    {   
        $data = array('requestee' => $arg);
        $this->load->view('change_password', $data);
    }
}
```

Here is the view:

```
     <form action="<?php echo site_url('login/change_password'); ?>" class="login-wrapper" method="post">
                      <div class="header">
                        <div class="row-fluid">
                          <div class="span12">
                            <h3>Change password<img src="<?php echo asset_url();?>img/logo1.png" alt="Logo" class="pull-right"></h3>
                            <p>Fill out the form below to change your password.</p>
                          </div>
                        </div>

                      </div>
                      <div class="content">
                        <div class="row-fluid">
                          <div class="span12">
                            <input class="input span12 password" id="" name="data[oldpassword]" placeholder="Old password" required="required" type="password" value="<?php echo set_value('oldpassword'); ?>">
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row-fluid">
                          <div class="span12">
                            <input class="input span12 password" id="" name="data[password]" placeholder="New password" required="required" type="password" value="<?php echo set_value('password'); ?>">
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row-fluid">
                          <div class="span12">
                            <input class="input span12 password" id="" name="data[passconf]" placeholder="Confirm new password" required="required" type="password" value="<?php echo set_value('passconf'); ?>" >
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="actions">
                        <input class="btn btn-danger" name="change_password" type="submit" value="Change" >

                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                      </div>
                    </form>
```

Comment: as i said I want to display a message that password was changed successfully when the password changes. How do I do that?

Comment: should i just add another if else statement and echo successful password change? if so where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that after changing the users password, you are using a redirect to return the user to another page.

In your controller, just before doing the redirect, You can use CodeIgniters session data to set a message in flashdata like so:

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Your Password Was Successfully Changed');
```

or 
    $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Your Password Was Not Changed');

Then in your view, you can add:

```
<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('message'); ?>
```

Please note that in order for this to work, if you have not done so already, you will need to either manually load the session library on every page where it is used or add it to your autoload.php file.

Comment: thanks that was helpful, already added the session library in my autoload.php